# Which is most accepted - USD100 or USD 100?

Tags: currency

With or without space after currency code? I'm seeing different versions. [Here](https://bit.ly/391fu4q) it says USD 100 but [here](https://www.stylemanual.gov.au/grammar-punctuation-and-conventions/numbers-and-measurements/currency) is USD100.

Which is the most accepted term?

Comment: The two "here" links are the same link, and it does not seem to contain either USD 100 or USD100 without the \$ symbol.

Comment: @Giskard Sorry, I fixed it.